# Douts with flavors and packages names

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

I have two `Flavors` on my app, so my project has this structure:

```
productFlavors {
            green {
                resValue "string", "app_name", "green"
                minSdkVersion 14
                applicationId 'com.company.green'
                targetSdkVersion 22
                versionCode 3
                versionName '3.0.3'
            }

            red {
                resValue "string", "app_name", "red"
                minSdkVersion 14
                applicationId 'com.company.red'
                targetSdkVersion 22
                versionCode 3
                versionName '3.0.3'
                 }
             }
```

Also I have different class implementation in every `Flavor` and commun classes in the main package.
Now let´s say that I have to implement the class:

> MyClass

That class will have a different implementation for each flavor , so I am implementing the class inside of the green and red `Flavor`

After create `MyClass` on the green `Flavor` I am getting in the this error 
in the class itself.

> package name com.company.MyClass does not correspond to the file path

I have also try with

```
package com.company.green.MyClass
```

But I am getting the same package name error

So my question is :
What is correct package name for each `Flavor` ?

Comment: In what directory is this file (`MyClass.java`) located?

Comment: I will have to directories , one for the green flavor and the other one for the red, MyClass wiil be in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `MyClass.java` should be located in 2 places:
`<project>/<module>/src/green/java/com/company/MyClass.java`
`<project>/<module>/src/red/java/com/company/MyClass.java`

And should has `package com.company`,
so `applicationId` set in flavor doesn't affect the package name and location of classes.

Then you may do `import com.company.MyClass` anywhere in you project and appropriate version of `MyClass` will be taken.

[image: file tree]

For more details look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/artyomn/2ca522e32abc2dbdf695a730ef51e5a1).

Comment: It does not work, Android studio says that there are duplicated classes

Comment: Answer is fixed. You don't need to put `MyClass` in `main` because `main` and `flavor` sources are combined together and you get a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks but now I get package name com.company.MyClass does not correspond to the file path :(